# Regex to match specific url with or without extensions but not including subdomains, and to match relative paths

Tags: regex

I've got to match a slew of `urls` as well as `relative paths` that I need to match with `regex`, which could vary a great deal in their exact format, but will basically look like the following:

```
http://example.com/asbd
http://example.com/products/asdb
http://example.com/
/Products/product.aspx
/Products/random/articles.aspx
/Products/product
/Products/random/articles
```

So far I have the following:

```
http://(?:www\.| )*example\.com(?:/|)[A-Za-z0-9](.*)$
```

which matches

```
http://example.com/asbd
```

It is very important the regex **does not match** `subdomain urls` like the following:

```
http://careers.example.com/
http://investor.example.com/asdf
http://newsroom.example.com/
```

Comment: Just guessing: [`(?:http://(?:www\.)?example\.com/?|/Products/)(?:[A-Za-z0-9].*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/yI6vM2/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following makes sure it's the main domain OR a relative link:

`^(?:http:\/\/(?:www\.)?example\.com)?(?:\/.*)$` => [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/cR5oG1/1)

Comment: @maudulus The demo says otherwhise !